# Get indentation value of line from currently selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building an extension for `VsCode` that adds in some text to the line after the `editor.active.selection` but I can't figure out how to get the indentation to match that of the previous line and insert the text to the new line.

I have now tried the following (code below) but the second `builder.insert` function never seems to target the correct line, it's as if it doesn't know the first `builder.insert` has created a new line already.

```ts
const endOfSelectedLine = editor.document.lineAt(activeSelection.line).range.end;
const indentValue = editor.document.lineAt(activeSelection.line).firstNonWhitespaceCharacterIndex;
const insertPosition = activeSelection.with(activeSelection.line + 1, indentValue);

editor.edit(builder => {
    builder.insert(endOfSelectedLine, '\n');
    builder.insert(insertPosition, 'hello');
});
```